# Autostart script to notify me on connection issues

Tags: networking, indicator, ping

My network connection is sometimes not very stable and starts to drop packages or entirely break every now and then, which requires me to restart the network connection or sometimes temporarily unplug some devices.

This is most probably not an Ubuntu issue but has to do with the hardware and environmental influences and interferences.

What I want would be to get notified (pop-up window or indicator applet) as soon as my connection starts to break. Detecting this works by checking the `ping` responses of my local router, if I can reach it, everything is ok.

Can you please provide me a script that pings my router about every second if the connection is active? It should check for lost packages and alert me if one does not come back.

Comment: you may also be interested in the `ethtool` command which shows you low level details about the link, such as what speed it autonegociated to, how many error packets were received, and whether the cable is even detected at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
dev='eth0'

if { nmcli dev status | grep "^"$dev".* connected" ;} &>/dev/null; then
  while :; do
    if ping -c 4 -i 0.5 gmail.com &>/dev/null; then
        sleep 5
    else
        sleep 30
        until ping -c 4 -i 0.5 gmail.com &>/dev/null; do
          notify-send --urgency=critical "Network issue"
          sleep 30
        done
        notify-send --urgency=critical "There was a Network issue, Its Ok now"
    fi
  done
fi
```

Save the interface you want to monitor as variable `dev`.

This script will first check if the connection is Up, if it is up then it will send 4 ICMP echo request packets with 0.5 seconds interval to 192.168.1.1 (assuming this is your routers IP address). If any of the packets have echo response from the router then it will wait for 5 seconds before stating the `ping` check again.

Now if all 4 of the packets failed to get the response from router then it will sleep for 30 seconds so that we are not overwhemed by sudden network blip. After 30 seconds it will start checking with `ping` again, if succeeds this time the message `There was a Network issue, Its Ok now` will be shown.

If it not Ok still, then the message `Network issue` will be shown, then it will wait for 30 seconds and will start looping again until any successful response is received.

Comment: If I know right, `ping -c 4` will send 4 packages with a delay of 1 second each, if not set different wit `-i`. And I don't want that on connection loss for a few minutes, I get hundreds of notifications. Also this does not yet check whether the connection is enabled at all. It might be disabled manually and should not alert in that case.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yeah..did not check it thoroughly..check my edits..

Comment: You used google.com instead of local IP address, but doesn't matter. But I think no `sleep` is needed here, as `ping` already blocks until all packages are received again or time out. And will it notify if at least one package out of the 4 got lost or will it notify when all of the 4 packages were dropped?

Comment: @ByteCommander That was from my test probably..i was on the phone then..here `sleep` will add more seconds over `ping` delay, also the blocking effect of ping will be minimum if we use `192.168.1.1` as it will should just one hop..i would suggest you to increase `sleep` value for unsuccessful case e.g. `sleep 15` so that a short network blip won't keep notifying after short times..ping returns true if one of the packets is returned successfully, no matter how many we send..also if you need any added functionality let me know..

Comment: Would it be possible to create a little popup window (just like an error popup with OK button and short text message) that shows up if the network is down for a longer time (say 30 seconds), whereas it shows (only!) one notification bubble if it gets restored before that time?

Comment: @ByteCommander check my edits..